# Skip optimistic locking for one method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, optimistic-locking

In my project we run a sync operation which fails sometimes because of the StaleObjectError exception.

- Is there any way to skip updating lock_version when record is being saved to db through this method?
- any way to skip optimistic locking for one particular method?

Tried using object.reload but that does not work. The call to object.save! is inside a transaction block. 
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `object.reload` before saving the updated object and also to ensure that you're not passing `lock_version` via form (or params).